# Spark SQL query optimization techniques

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sqlperformance

I have recently been introduced to `Spark-SQL` and trying to wrap my head around it. I am looking to learn best practices, tips and tricks used for optimization of Spark-SQL queries. 
Most importantly, I wish to learn about interpreting `Spark SQL` **EXPLAIN** plans. I have searched online searching for books/articles on `Spark SQL` Explain but ended up with almost nothing.

Can anyone please help me and orient me in the right direction.

Due to Spark's architectural difference to traditional RDBMS, there are many relational optimization options that doesn't apply to Spark (e.g. leveraging indexes etc). 
I could not find many resources related exclusively to Spark-SQL. I wish to learn about the best tips/techniques (eg, usage of hints, order of tables in join clauses i.e. keeping the largest table at the end of the joining conditions etc) to write efficient queries for `Spark-SQL`.

Most importantly, any resources on understanding and leveraging `Spark-SQL` `Explain Plans` will be great.
However, please note that I have access only to Spark-SQL but **Not** PySpark SQL.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hey. You could find this talk useful https://youtu.be/99fYi2mopbs

Comment: In the first instance, why don't you try reording tables and see if it makes a difference? This (the first result when I googled "spark does table order matter" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694523/in-spark-join-does-table-order-matter-like-in-pig says no. My understanding of spark is that it has a lot to do with getting maximum parallelism due to correct partitioning of data

Comment: This book could answer all your queries https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/spark-the-definitive/9781491912201/